# Shall I test different classes separately using Boost.Test?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I'm using Boost.Test with Xcode to test my C++ program. There are several ways to do so.

1. Test each class separately. That is, I should start multiple projects, one project for each class. Boost should provide the `main()`.
2. I should use my own `main()` written using Boost.Program_Options. A test option should be added and when invoked all functions other than `main()` will be tested.

I'm new to Boost.Test. Which option is better?

Comment: I'm currently working on a VS solution with something like 150 projects.  More than 140 of them are single-cpp test projects.  Keep your tests in separate suites?  Absolutely!  Different CPP files for different classes?  Heck yeah.  Different /projects/?  I recommend not going this route for non-trivial systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a C++ developer, I would advise you to maintain a separate unit test suite for each production source code file. Use "Test" as a prefix/suffix to name the test suite.
So, to my opinion, option 1.

Cheers